# script bundles of angular2 rc

Tags: angular, rc, bundles

I try to migrate my app to RC 0   from 0.17 
and I have some questions.
In 0.17 we use  those scripts (bundles)

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```

But how I can include all of this in RC 0 ? I can't found some bundles in @angular  package  and in tutorial there is no exist some explanation about this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no angular2-polyfills.js in RC versions. You need to directly add Zones and Reflect metadata:

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

Regarding the other modules, Angular2 doesn't (yet?) provide bundled versions so you need to configure them within the SystemJS configuration. It's not really efficient for an application in production so you need some packaging...